# Remove double quotes from a value saving in the variable using postman

Tags: postman

I have a piece of code as below, that I am using in the postman:

```
bodyData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var value = bodyData.data[2].first_name;
console.log(value);
```

Variable "value" returning a name with double quotations like `"Tobias"`, but I want to remove the double quotations with the name in the variable "value", below is the image as well

[image]

And I am using below piece of code:

```
var string1 = "'foo'";

function removeFirstAndLastQuotes(str){
  var firstChar = str.charAt(0);
  var lastChar = str[str.length -1];
  //double quotes
  if(firstChar && lastChar === String.fromCharCode(34)){
    str = str.slice(1, -1);
  }
  //single quotes
  if(firstChar && lastChar === String.fromCharCode(39)){
    str = str.slice(1, -1);
  }
  return str;
}
document.write(removeFirstAndLastQuotes(string1));
```

This is working for the javascript, but not working in the postman means still showing the name with the double quotes like `"Tobias"`

Comment: Where are you seeing the extra double quotes? In the Postman Console? Or is this causing your request to fail? This image doesn't show what you mean.

Comment: Yes, in the postman console

Comment: That's just how `strings` are represented in the Postman Console. It's not saved like that as a variable.

Comment: But, I want to use without double quotation, is there any way to remove

Comment: If you're sending a string value to the Postman Console, it's going to look like that. It would be the same if you were sending a `number/object/array` those would be represented in that format.